# Dropping 50VAC to 10VAC-20VAC

Tags: voltage, resistors

I am installing a Ring door bell.  At the old intercom I have 50VAC currently (NO other source).  According to the manufacturer I need between 8VAC and 24VAC.  My question is what resistance (resisters) would I need to reduce the voltage?

The input is 50vac, I can NOT get a source of 120vac. Could I go with a regulator that has a steady 12vac output instead?  Just not sure it can take the 50VAC input. I am located in California.

Thanks!!!

Comment: A transformer would be ideally suited for the task. Why are you set on resistors?

Comment: @winny Probably because the company making Ring doorbells has thoroughly obfuscated documentation. Heck, their _datasheet_ calls current limiting resistor "a device to increase your chime efficiency"

Comment: @Maple. Strange. Perhaps high voltage + resistor may yield a bit more attack to the sound than just straight low voltage. Anyhow, this guy needs a transformer. Any 2:1 should do.

Comment: @winny I suspect to save the cost they oversimplified battery charging circuit to the point where it needs external current limiting at 24V supply, which they trying to hide by obscure wording. That is why I'd rather stick to low side of input range with 5:1 transformer

Answer (score 3):

Using resistors in this way doesn't usually work very well. It is a reasonable approach only if the input voltage is constant, the required current is fairly low, and the required current is constant. I would suggest that you look for a transformer instead, one that has a primary-to-secondary ratio of 2:1 or 3:1

Comment: The input is 50vac, I can not get a source of 120vac.  I would go with a regulator that has a steady 12vac output, but am not sure it can take the 50VAC input.  Yes, I am located in California.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a resistor. You need a transformer. Either reducing existing 50V to required voltage, or (preferably) replacing it altogether for direct reduction of mains voltage. You should be able to reuse existing power wires for Ring doorbell.

BTW, I could not find any Ring models requiring 5~24V. They only have 8~24V or 16~24V, so check your specifications carefully before buying the transformer. Ideally, use simple [wall adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B077XTJBXV) sold by amazon. It would be cheaper and safer than tinkering with your own wiring.

Read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179721/) for explanation why resistor is a bad idea.

> The input is 50vac, I can not get a source of 120vac

Those 50VAC coming from *somewhere*. You should be able to locate existing transformer. See [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/86038/can-a-doorbell-transformer-sit-loose-inside-main-panel) for how it looks and how it could be installed.

You can replace it with similar transformer for new voltage output, like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019BW9VZ2) for example, but this could be dangerous as it involves connection to mains voltage. If you are not confident in your skills, you can disconnect two wires from it (safe if you do not short those screws on top) and use the wall adapter like the one I linked above to send power along those wires.

---

**UPDATE:**

To avoid misunderstanding, here is what I mean:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw75LV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, your existing 50V transformer has ratio about 2.4:1 (if you divide primary by secondary voltage, 120V / 50V = 2.4). To reduce those 50V down to 10V you need another transformer with 5:1 ratio (50V / 10V = 5).

The transformer on Ring website is 7.5:1 (120V / 16V = 7.5). You need 5:1 ~ 3:1 transformer. For example 24V mains transformer has a ratio 120V / 24V = 5 and 40V transformer has a ratio 120V / 40V = 3. Here are some suitable 24V transformers: [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BQY88I), [two](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PSMWVM0), [three](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BQNA1O).

**WARNING: the above only works if you indeed have 50VAC power**

The reason for this warning is that I do not know of intercoms working on 50VAC. As far as I know they usually work on 12, 30 or 48 **VDC**. The doorbells usually work on 8, 16 or 24 **VAC** (this is what Ring doorbells are designed to work with).

It would be **very helpful** if you can confirm that your intercom voltage is indeed 50VAC and specify Intercom model and Ring model you have.

It would also be helpful if you explain what you are going to do with your existing intercom. If you replacing it with Ring devices then you certainly can use existing wiring with new wall adapter or mains transformer, regardless of what voltage intercom was using.

Comment: The 50VAC is coming from an existing and still operating intercom system.  I can not modify the 50VAC from the source, I need to work with the 50VAC and reduce it to the 8~24VAC.

Comment: Well, then as I said in the beginning, you can use transformer to reduce 50V to your requirements. Any turns ratio between 1:3 and 1:5 should work. Guessing from mains transformer sold on Ring site you don't need more that 30 Watt, so 4A rated transformer should be enough

Comment: So I can take a 120v transformer and still feed 50v on the primary to get the 16vac as shown on Rings website?  https://shop.ring.com/collections/accessories/products/hardwired-transformer?variant=5433572556831

Comment: Yes, you can take 120V to 24V (or 120 to 40) transformer and feed 50VAC to the primary to get 10 (or 17) VAC on secondary. See an update in the answer above

Answer (score 2):

As has been stated, a resistor is a bad idea. Instead, get a 120 volt (I'm assuming you're in the US, with 120 volt power) to 24 volt transformer. It's output will be about (50/120) x 24, or 10 volts. This is comfortably between your 5 and 24 limits, and they are cheap.