# How do I provide constant voltage to a load?

Tags: voltage

Say, I have 5V supply and I use voltage divider to have 2.5V and 2.5V across each of them. Suppose, I want to power a microcontroller (input impedance of 200Ω) which requires exactly 2.5V but once I connect it   in parallel, the voltage across each component changes.
Is there a way to feed it using the voltage divider at constant voltage?

Comment: No. This is why we use regulators.

Comment: Very similar previous question: [How to reduce dc voltage using resistors?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75448/how-to-reduce-dc-voltage-using-resistors/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your voltage divider has equal resistances above and below its midpoint. Since the current is the same through both, the voltages are the same across each, and you find yourself dividing the voltage in half: 2.5V and 2.5V.

Now, if you add a current drain from the midpoint to ground, you change the currents and thus the voltages. And yes: this breaks your 2.5V "supply".

If your microcontroller indeed has a constant input impedance of 200Ω (drawing a constant 12.5mA at 2.5V), then you could just supply it from the 5V supply through a 200Ω resistor. Bingo: you've got a new equal divider, and the microcontroller will get its 2.5V. But I seriously doubt that a micro would draw a constant current; the current almost certainly depends on what its code is, and if you're driving any external loads then all bets are off.

Another option would be to return to your original voltage divider, but make sure that the current through the dividers is much larger than the current through the microcontroller. Example: if you used two 10Ω resistors, then adding the 200Ω micro load would only pull the center voltage down from 2.5V to 2.44V, and variances in the micro's load wouldn't change that much. Then again, you'd be drawing 250mA through the divider, and you'd have to use 1W resistors. Probably not a great tradeoff.

So, I'd follow @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' advice, and get yourself a 2.5V regulator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "constant voltage" in practice as there will always be some noise or ripple on it to a varying degree.

The current draw is not constant for the microcontroller (and is missing from your question), so you will have to look at the datasheet for that.

Can you do a voltage divider? Yes. What are the drawbacks? Power efficiency (the resistors will be dissipating power as heat. The more "constant" the voltage in this case, you will want lower value resistors, which means more current (and more heat).

Or, you can use an LDO regulator and be done with it. Check that out.