# What kind of LED do I need?

Tags: led

I want to learn about analogue circuit design and thought I'd start of reeeaaally simple, with a circuit where you connect the battery and the LED turns on. I've been looking on digikey.nz for the right components but they don't seem to offer the kind of LED I'm looking for.

I want a small LED that's simple to work with, something that looks like this:
[image]

Does anybody know what the name of this kind of LED is, and where I can get one? I've been trying to find a place to order one online but can only find lines of christmas lights, LED bulbs, or weird complicated circular things.

Comment: Google up "5mm red LED" and see things like this: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9590

Comment: If you are really planning to buy from Digikey then 1) search "5mm LED" 2) Select "LED indication - discrete" 3) Select "Oval with Domed Top 5mm" from "Lens Style/Size" filter then apply. You will find a lot of 5mm LEDs. Pick one according to color, price etc.

Comment: Digikey shipping is a bit expensive in australia and NZ. Wouldn't element14 be better?

Comment: Your really simple circuit requires a current limit resistor (not as simple as you thought huh LOL).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Learn how to search Distributor's using any search engine

- Use a description of desired specs in any search engine or use their website with key words , use shopping tab in Google or include Digikey as a key word
- or use their website and "drill down" the Product Index

  **- = Product Index > Optoelectronics > LED Indication - Discrete**

[image]

[**results**](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/optoelectronics/led-indication-discrete/524729?k=&pkeyword=&pv7=3&pv1989=0&pv37=1&pv525=4&pv1843=3&pv543=29&pv69=80&FV=fff40008%2Cfff801b9&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500) < here

- Click **V** descending sort on brightest LED [mcd] or Millicandella Rating

[**My pick for you**](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/marktech-optoelectronics/MT5470E-UR/1125-1193-ND/4214626)   MT5470E-UR Marktech ( Private label Distributor)

- Oval Red **diffused tinted** lens **2300mcd** 40x110 deg radial

  - $0.29 usd (100pcs)

These are rated at 2.1V @20mA and have an equivalent zener resistance of 7 Ohms.

{#1 Choice} Red in clear lens  $0.11usd (100pc)

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cree-inc/C4SMF-RJF-CT0W0BB1/C4SMF-RJF-CT0W0BB1-ND/2809664

n.b. If you want **deep Red** (660 nmD) **not as bright** but lower Vf, 1.3V GaAs in Diffused tinted Red  > Search

[image]
However the easiest to use are 12V strip LEDs with built in resistors THAT OPERATE BRIGHTEST AT 14.2v FOR CARS

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffKmIm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Excellent answer, well structured and formatted text, good illustrating images.